# Adding objects to an NSmutableArray from a C Array

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsarray

I have an NSmutable array and I am adding some strings present in the C array to it. By using this method

```
if (!self.arrayOfVariableNames) {
        self.arrayOfVariableNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i< cols; i++) {
            [self.arrayOfVariableNames addObject:[NSString stringWithCString:cArrayOfVariableNames[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];
        }
    }
    else{
        [self.arrayOfVariableNames removeAllObjects];
        for (int i = 0; i< cols; i++) {
        [self.arrayOfVariableNames addObject:[NSString stringWithCString:cArrayOfVariableNames[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];
        }
    }
```

Does this method ensure that the objects in the NSmutableArray won't be deallocated when the C array is taken out of memory?

Comment: YES ..Are you facing any problems ?

Comment: Actually a lot of problems. I am a self taught programmer and I am almost about to give up as I cant figure out certain things. I have to use this Array in a table view but by the time the tableview datasource methods are implemented, this array becomes null.

Comment: If your NSArray is becoming nil your not keeping a strong reference to it. Make it a property of your controller.

Comment: All arrays have strong reference. There is an NSTableView in a seperate ViewController which uses this this tableview for data and when I log the contents, I am getting an error

Comment: How are you passing the array to the second view controller?

Comment: I made the first viewController as the datasource and delegate. The issues is, this table is loading when I use another array(just a simple one). I had posted my project. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nn3qc1irb1ody85/Solver.zip?dl=0. If you are free, please go through it. Thanks a ton

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code where you refer to `self.arrayOfVariableNames` in a tableview method

Comment: I am just NSlogging it. It is returning null. In ScratchWindowController.m
`-(id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`
 method

Comment: The problem is that when you click the "show results" button you instantiate a new view controller that has your tableview.  This table view has *an* instance of `ScratchViewController` as the tableview delegate, but this is not the same instance as the one that contains the results - so you end up with empty arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this array `arrayOfVariableNames` is becoming Null, then the problem is with the initialisation of the array. Please try to use Lazy loading by doing this:

```
- (NSArray*)arrayOfVariableNames {
    if (!_arrayOfVariableNames) {
        _arrayOfVariableNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //initialise the array if needed
    }
    return _arrayOfVariableNames;  //else return the already initialized array
}
```

and please comment out this line in your code: `self.arrayOfVariableNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

******EDIT******
Please find the update code in https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BybTW7Dwp2_vdHhQN1p1UzExdTA/edit?pli=1. Have a look at it.

Comment: I do realize that this is too much to ask but if you can take a look at my code, I will be very glad. It is not working as expected.

Comment: Sure I can ..send me a link.

Comment: Here is a dropbox link. Please read the README. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nn3qc1irb1ody85/Solver.zip?dl=0

Comment: here is the project link. Please read the README https://www.dropbox.com/s/nn3qc1irb1ody85/Solver.zip?dl=0

Comment: Here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BybTW7Dwp2_vdHhQN1p1UzExdTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes u can check it. The array is now getting logged properly. In case it works for you. Accept the answer

Comment: This doesn't fix the underlying problem, which is caused by the second view controller instantiating a new instance of `ScratchViewController` - which has empty arrays.

Comment: I have removed the view controller object that was there in the `ResultView.xib`. It is not instantiating another instance. Put a breakpoint in `awakeFromNib` for `ScratchViewController.m`. It is called only once.

Comment: Oops.  Yes, sorry. I missed that.  I suggest you update your answer

Comment: @croyneaus4u could you please tell me what you've done?

Comment: @croyneaus4u    Yes. I am wondering because the datasource is not mentioned anywhere but still somehow the tableview is getting updated.

Comment: The datasource and Delaware are added in the changecontroller method. Check there.

Comment: Thanks a million. I could buy you a great cup of coffee

Answer (score 0):

Yes. NSArray retains anything in it. 
But you should stop chaining your NSString creation and instead creat a string a line before adding it to the array. Then check for nil. 
Only add it to the array if it is not nil. 
Do code defensively.

Comment: The NSStrings copy in data from the C-strings so they won't be modified when the C-strings get deallocated, and the NSArray will retain copies of the NSStrings so the NSStrings will not be released..

Comment: The point is that you may not guarantee that you will get a NSString back from the C string. It can fail for many reasons. You cannot add nil to an NSArray or NSMutableArray.

Comment: I didn't see a [string returning with nil](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithCString:encoding:) in the docs, but you make a really good point. I was trying to clarify that the C-strings get copied into the NSStrings and hence persist after the C-strings are deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayOfVariableNames` will not change when the C array get deallocated.

Make sure that your `arrayOfVariableNames` variable is `strong`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfVariableNames;

    if (!self.arrayOfVariableNames) 
    {
      self.arrayOfVariableNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else
    {
      [self.arrayOfVariableNames removeAllObjects];
    }

   for (int i = 0; i< cols; i++) 
   {
       NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithCString:cArrayOfVariableNames[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       if([tempString length] > 0)
       {
         [self.arrayOfVariableNames addObject:tempString];
       }
       else
       {
         NSLog(@"string is empty");
       }
   }
```